# Can I create categories or attribute contain more than 70,000?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tags

I'm will making a website for advertising services in the property sector using wordpress and woocommerce.

I created categories consisting of provinces, cities and sub-districts that number more than 70,000 (In my country).

However, the products that will be displayed will only be cities and sub-districts.
(Please don't misunderstand the number 70,000)

I know, when I started maybe just 1 or 2 categories (regions).

However I'm worried if as the number of categories keeps growing, it make a matter.

I have to think about how I am responsible to customers considering the business I have

Please advise before I go too far.

thank you
(Sorry if my english is bad)

note : Hopefully the illustration below can give you a hint of what I want.

- Provinces A

  - Cities A1
  - Cities A2

    - Subdistrict X1
    - Subdistrict X2
    - Subdistrict X3 - 900
- Provinces B

  - Cities B1
  - Cities B2

    - Subdistrict Y1
    - Subdistrict Y2
    - Subdistrict Y3 - 400
- Provinces C -...Z

Totally Subdistrict from Provinces A to Z over 70,000

Example on front end :

- Product A (Title, Image, Description, etc)

  - Category : Sub-district X2, Cities A2
- Product B (Title, Image, Description, etc)

  - Category : Sub-district Y2, Cities B2

Currently all is well. But i doubt input this data (region) must on categories or attributes. I'm worried that in the future there will be about limitation / ability to accommodate data considering the amount is not small and it a becomes problem. Can you give me advise?

[Display on shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL36T.jpg)
[Display on additional information (Location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3dxX.jpg)

Comment: I think you should ask this the Yith support.

Comment: hi @kero

I have revised my problem.

Maybe you want to see it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not understand with this, so my thoughts are split between wanting to create a large number of attributes or putting them into categories. Sorry about this

Comment: Why not try it out with eg wp-cli commands or test script

Comment: hi @birgire

Thank you for replying.

I'll try and find out about it.
If you have a reference or guide please let me know.

That would be very helpful

Comment: Maybe a starting point https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392966/sample-test-data-for-large-wordpress-install/392971#392971

Comment: or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324129/how-to-create-450-categories-in-wp/324157#324157